# Passing variables from Controller to Mailables in Laravel [php]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my `UserController` I have a function

```
public function userFollow($id)
    {
        $authuser = Auth::user();
        $authuser->follow($id);
        //mail goes to the followiee ($id)
        $followiee = User::where('id', $id)->first();
        $to = $followiee->email;
        Mail::to($to)->send(new MyMail);
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Following User');
    }
```

I have also created a Mailable `MyMail`

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome');
    }
}
```

Inside my welcome email I need to access some variables like `$to` which is defined in the `UserController`

I tried the following in MyMail Mailable:

```
 public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome',['to' => $to]);
    }
```

But I am getting `Undefined variable: to`

How to pass variables from Controller to Mailables?

**Update:**

What I have tried so far:

**UserController**

```
Mail::to($to)->send(new MyMail($to));
```

**MyMail**

```
    public $to;
    public function __construct($to)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome');
    }
```

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
 {{ $to }}
```

**Error:**

```
FatalErrorException in Mailable.php line 442:
[] operator not supported for strings
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to pass variables to the `MyMail` constructor, like this:

**UserController**

```
Mail::to($to)->send(new MyMail($to));
```

**MyMail**

```
public $myTo;

public function __construct($to)
{
    $this->myTo = $to;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.welcome');
}
```

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
{{ $myTo }}
```

**Update:**
As @Rahul noted in his answer, the `$to` property can be defined as public. And in this case the `view` will be populated with it automatically.

**Update 2:**
You just need to give a different name to your `$to` variable (e.g. `$myTo`) to distinguish it from the `$to` in the `Mailable.php` which is defined as `public $to = [];`.

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting an error
`Access level to App\Mail\MyMail::$to must be public (as in class Illuminate\Mail\Mailable)`

Comment: In order to make public you dont need to pass it as parameter, see the method 1 of below solution

Comment: I tried @Rahul method too, but I got another error `FatalErrorException in Mailable.php line 442:
[] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: Awesome, changing it to a different variable worked!

Comment: So trying to pass a custom string variable in the constructor of a mailable in Laravel 5.5 gives me a `BindingResolutionException`, saying `"Unresolvable dependency resolving"` as if it thinks the string is a dependency... Is it required to pass only dependency objects in 5.5 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you may make data available to your view.

> 1. First, any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $to;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($to)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome'); // $to will be automatically passed to your view
    }
}
```

> 2. Second you may manually pass your data to the view via the `with` method however you will still pass data via the mailable class'
>      constructor; however, you should set this data to protected or 
>      private properties so the data is not automatically made available to
>      the template.

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

      protected $to;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($to)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome',['to'=>$to]);


     }
    }
```

Comment: in the 1st method, you have not passed $to in the constructor.
Although I tried your 1st method by passing the variable to the constructor, it didnt work for me.

Comment: @thehackwall I have written `$this->to = $to;` in 1st method

Comment: But you need to pass the argument like this also right? `public function __construct($to)`

Comment: ohhh yes my mistake